# GCS encryption always fails on big files

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to encrypt a file on GCS with my own key using [gsutil rewrite](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rewrite) command (following https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-encryption-keys)

As instructed I'm using a boto file including 

`[GSUtil]
encryption_key = p9syBNA0ycKxGotK3XinNZC6aCpdn3ZQ7WWOhKNgBaY=`

It is working without a problem on small files but fails constantly on big ones.
I'm running the command:

`gsutil rewrite -k -O gs://ywz-tmp/bigfile.txt`

Is that a know issue?
Any workaround?

Feel free to use the file and key (both were generated for this post)

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the specific failure you're seeing?  What sizes of files fail?

Comment: @TravisHobrla the problem starts around 200M I believe.
gsutil cp works, it is just rewrite which fails.

Comment: A workaround I'm using:
`gsutil ls -L gs://MY_BUKCET/**|awk -v RS="]" -v FS="\n" '! /Encryption algorithm:   AES256/ {print$2}'|sed 's/:$//'|xargs -P 15 -n 1 -I @@ bash -c 'gsutil cat @@ |gsutil cp - @@'`

Comment: I was able to reproduce this issue with a 500MiB file, my current thinking is that it is a bug with the GCS service, so I am following up on that.

Answer (score 1):

The fix for this issue should be in production now.